# Problem with subscribing to a topic that contains slash

Tags: ros, namespace, topic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed something weird that seems like a bug. When a subscriber listens to a topic that contains a slash and that a publisher advertises the "parent" topic (the part before the slash), then the subscriber changes the topic to what it listens to match the publisher.

Here is an example. I open three terminals that will exchange on topic `/parent/child`.

Step 1: In Terminal 1, I start `rostopic echo /parent/child`

Step 2: In Terminal 2, I start `rostopic echo /parent`

Step 3: In Terminal 3, I start a node with publishers for `/parent` and `parent/child`

Step 4: In Terminal 3, the node publishes on both topics

The result is that only the subscriber in Terminal 2 gets the message. In addition, rxgraph shows that Terminal 1 is then subscribing to /parent instead of /parent/child. In Terminal 1, I get this instead of the message: `no field named [/child]`

What's happening here?

Here is the code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{  
    ros::init(argc, argv, "MyPublisher");

    ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
    
    ros::Rate oneSecond(1);

    // Creates a publisher to see if it replicates the bug
    ros::Publisher pubParent = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/parent", 10);
    
    // Waits for the subscribers to connect
    oneSecond.sleep();
    
    ros::Publisher pubChild = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/parent/child", 10);
    
    // Waits for the subscribers to connect
    oneSecond.sleep();

    
    std_msgs::String msgChild;
    msgChild.data = "Hello World! (on /parent/child)";
    pubChild.publish(msgChild);
    ROS_INFO("Message published (on /parent/child)");
    
    
    std_msgs::String msgParent;
    msgParent.data = "Hello World! (on /parent)";
    pubParent.publish(msgParent);
    ROS_INFO("Message published (on /parent)");
    
    // Waits for the user to manually stop the node (to give time to see the update in rxgraph)
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the info about the nodes:

Terminal 1:

```
Node [/rostopic_27422_1352897219007]
Publications: 
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: 
 * /parent [std_msgs/String]

Services: None
Pid: 27422
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /parent
    * to: /MyPublisher (http://dfki-benoit:33822/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

Terminal 2:

```
Node [/rostopic_27405_1352897218194]
Publications: 
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: 
 * /parent [std_msgs/String]

Services: None
Pid: 27405
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /parent
    * to: /MyPublisher (http://dfki-benoit:33822/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

Terminal 3:

```
Node [/MyPublisher]
Publications: 
 * /parent [std_msgs/String]
 * /parent/child [std_msgs/String]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: None

Services: 
 * /MyPublisher/get_loggers
 * /MyPublisher/set_logger_level
Pid: 27455
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /parent
    * to: /rostopic_27405_1352897218194
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /parent
    * to: /rostopic_27422_1352897219007
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

EDIT (12/12/12): Following the answer from @Dirk Thomas, I tried his Python script. The behavior that I observe is the following. If I start the standard Python listener and `rostopic echo`, they both receive the messages on `/parent/child`. However, if I start only `rostopic echo`, then it "switches" to `/parent` and tries to read the field `/child`. In addition, `rostopic echo` does not print the `WARNING: topic [/parent/child] does not appear to be published yet` if the standard listener was started before.

These observations mean that the presence of a standard listener changes the behavior of `rostopic echo`.

In my opinion, this is unintuitive and most importantly not "repeatable". It means that my scripts using `rostopic echo` would yield different results if my colleagues started some listeners on the ROS network, for example.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48086/problem-with-subscribing-to-a-topic-that-contains-slash/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-12**:
What's the output of `rosnode info` on the two subscriber nodes?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-12**:
Does the subscription for 1 change in between the other steps? I cannot reproduce this with rostopic echo/pub. For me in step 4 both rostopic echo get the message.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-13**:
No, the `rosnode info` for Terminal 1 does not change between steps, other than adding the publisher when I start it in Step 2. The subscriber in Terminal 1 thus starts on `/eoi`.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-13**:
Can you reproduce the exact steps (after a roscore restart) using standard messages? This looks like a weird bug to me.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-13**:
Ok, I'll come up with a minimal example that shows this behavior

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-14**:
I can confirm this by following step 1 and 2 and then `rostopic pub -r 5 /parent/ std_msgs/String -- "{data: Hello}"`. It only works after a roscore restart. When a publisher for /parent and /parent/child are present before the subscribers are started everything works fine.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-14**:
Either you are not allowed to have a topic at /parent while there is one at /parent/child (thus parent becoming a namespace) or this is a bug that should be filed. In any case something is wrong as I can get both subscriptions to run depending on the order. It should be always or never.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-14**:
I think that's definitely a bug and should be filed. Even if that's desired behavior, it is not intuitive and at least a warning or error should be thrown. Nice catch...

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-15**:
I filed this issue: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/24

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-12-11**:
I would suggest that rostopic echo take a -f option to list the fields to be displayed within a topic. Not providing this option would display all fields (standard current behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As guessed by felix k before this is intended behavior of `rostopic echo`. It subscribes to parent topics and attempts to extract field names with that name from the messages.

When the subscription is performed in a node it will not auto magically subscribe to the parent topic. You can try the following Python script sub.py with the argument `/parent` or `/parent/child` instead of invoking rostopic:

````
import sys
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + 'Incoming message: %s',data.data)
rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
rospy.Subscriber(sys.argv[1], String, callback)
rospy.spin()```



---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2012-11-21


This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-12-11**:\
I added the results of an experiment with this script to the question. I'd be interested to know if you expected this behavior, or if something weird is going on.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-12-12**:\
My guess: With the python subscriber the `/full/topic` is announced to the system, despite missing any publisher. The `rostopic echo` sees this (when started afterwards) and accepts it as the topic, therefore no warning.
````

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this happens because you *can* do a `rostopic echo` directly on a field (or a field of a field...) of a message topic, instead of echoing the full message.

See the [last example in the documentation](http://ros.org/wiki/rostopic#rostopic_echo).

I havn't looked into rostopic code but it might check that `/parent/child` isn't an existing topic, then strips it down to `/parent` beeing the topic and `/child` the message field. Though that topic also does not yet exist it might hang on that guess, therefore expecting named field in that topic's message.

Addendum: the conclusion would be not to start such an `rostopic echo` without registering the topic itself previously.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-15**:
Your guess is also my guess. :-) However, it's probably not related to rostopic. This is a minimal example, but the real integrated system uses real nodes, no rostopic. The subscriber will also always be running (i.e. before the publisher). Temporary workaround: use topic /eoi_confirmation.